# Using a combination of MapWhen and ApplicationBuilder in .net core app startup?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, middleware, startup

Is it possible to have partially a branching startup?

As an example, is it possible to have something like:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.AlwaysUseThisMiddleware();
    app.MapWhen(conditionA, appBuilder => {appBuilder.SometimesUseThisOne;})
    app.MapWhen(conditionB, appBuilder => {appBuilder.SometimesUseThisOtherOne;})
```

Or do I need to put the `AlwaysUseThisMiddleware` inside each branching? Like so:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.MapWhen(conditionA, appBuilder =>
    {
        appBuilder.AlwaysUseThisMiddleware(); // Duplicated
        appBuilder.SometimesUseThisOne;
    )
    app.MapWhen(conditionB, appBuilder =>
    {
        appBuilder.AlwaysUseThisMiddleware(); // Duplicated
        appBuilder.SometimesUseThisOtherOne;
    )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short Answer** :

Yes. It will work as you expected.

---

Actually, when we `Use()` a series of middlewares, we're registering a series of middlewares that will be invoked in sequence when processing requests.

The `MapWhen()` method is no more than a helper method [that invokes the `Use()`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/e6d77a1f6c1c87425e7820e6ded1ce527a66050d/src/Http/Http.Abstractions/src/Extensions/MapWhenExtensions.cs#L25-L53). What `MapWhen(predicate,configFn)` does is to registering something that runs [as below](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Http/Http.Abstractions/src/Extensions/MapWhenMiddleware.cs#L51-L57) :

```
if (predicate(context)){
    await branch(context);
} else {
    await _next(context);
}
```

As a result, when we call `MapWhen()` , we're registering another middleware that branching the processing.

For example :

```
app.UseMiddleware<AlwaysUseThisMiddleware>();                

app.MapWhen(ctx=>ctx.Request.Query["a"]=="1", appBuilder =>{
    appBuilder.UseMiddleware<SometimesUseThisOne>();
});

app.MapWhen(ctx=>ctx.Request.Query["b"]=="1", appBuilder =>{
    appBuilder.UseMiddleware<SometimesUseThisOtherOne>();
})

// ...
```

Basically, this code runs in the following way :

```
call  `AlwaysUseThisMiddleware`;

////////////////////////////////////
if (ctx.Request.Query["a"]=="1"){   
    call SometimesUseThisOne ;            
} else {
    //------------------------------------------
    if (ctx.Request.Query["b"]=="1"){
        call SometimesUseThisOtherOne ;
    } else {
        //##################################################
        await _next(context);  // call other middlewares ...
        //##################################################
    }
    //-----------------------------------------
}
////////////////////////////////////
```

Or it can also be rewritten as below if you like :

```
call `AlwaysUseThisMiddleware` middleware

if(ctx.Request.Query["a"]=="1")           // go to branch 1
    call `SometimesUseThisOne` middleware

else if (ctx.Request.Query["b"]=="1")     // go to branch 2
    call `SometimesUseThisOtherOne` middleware 

else :
    ...
```

Note here a branch is translated to `else if` instead of `if`. And the middleware `AlwaysUseThisMiddleware`  is always invoked before branch1 & branch2 .